# docker-compose taking a long time to start building

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have been using `docker-compose up --build -d` command for a while now and I have never had an issue with the build process and time. Today, when I ran `docker-compose up --build -d`, there is a very long delay (~ 1 minute) before it starts executing the build process. Below is the output for building my services:

```
Build authentication binary...
cd ../authentication-service && env GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o authApp ./cmd/api
Build api gateway binary...
cd ../api-gateway && env GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o apiGateway .
docker-compose down
[+] Running 4/3
 ✔ Container project-authentication-service-1  Removed                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s 
 ✔ Container project-api-gateway-1             Removed                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.1s 
 ✔ Container project-postgres-1                Removed                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s 
 ✔ Network project_default                     Removed                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.1s 
Building and starting docker images...
docker-compose up --build -d
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)  docker:desktop-linux
```

The build process hangs at
`[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)  docker:desktop-linux` before starting to load the Dockerfile and run the containers. This is rather strange and I have not faced this before. It will eventually run the containers but the part where it hangs is new to me.

Below is the finished output:

```
Build authentication binary...
cd ../authentication-service && env GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o authApp ./cmd/api
Build api gateway binary...
cd ../api-gateway && env GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o apiGateway .
docker-compose down
Building and starting docker images...
docker-compose up --build -d
[+] Building 63.5s (14/14) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                             docker:desktop-linux
 => [api-gateway internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                               10.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 118B                                                                                                                                                                                                                           10.0s
 => [api-gateway internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                  10.0s
 => => transferring context: 70B                                                                                                                                                                                                                               10.0s
 => [authentication-service internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                       10.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                10.0s
 => [authentication-service internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                    10.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 112B                                                                                                                                                                                                                           10.0s
 => [api-gateway internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                                                                                                                                                   23.3s
 => [api-gateway auth] library/alpine:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [authentication-service 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:latest@sha256:51b67269f354137895d43f3b3d810bfacd3945438e94dc5ac55fdac340352f48                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [api-gateway internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                  10.2s
 => => transferring context: 11.65MB                                                                                                                                                                                                                           10.2s
 => [authentication-service internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                       10.2s
 => => transferring context: 15.02MB                                                                                                                                                                                                                           10.2s
 => CACHED [authentication-service 2/3] RUN mkdir /app                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [api-gateway 3/3] COPY apiGateway /app                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [api-gateway] exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:171f01a47b5af04235e6dfbee9ac3f00ce1c50c7e6ac89699745aa1ddc78413b                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/project-api-gateway                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [authentication-service 3/3] COPY authApp /app                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [authentication-service] exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:766dfb2e64100c9d4f1c5acaefef52f721bc7e1b4e57021f34be12907f0e3f4b                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/project-authentication-service                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
[+] Running 4/4
 ✔ Network project_default                     Created                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.1s 
 ✔ Container project-postgres-1                Started                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.3s 
 ✔ Container project-api-gateway-1             Started                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.3s 
 ✔ Container project-authentication-service-1  Created
```

#### `docker-compose.yml` file

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  api-gateway:
    build:
      context: ./../api-gateway
      dockerfile: ./../api-gateway/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '80:80'

  authentication-service:
    build:
      context: ./../authentication-service
      dockerfile: ./../authentication-service/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8001:8001'
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
      POSTGRES_PORT: '5432'
      POSTGRES_DB: imsdb

  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:14.2'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    restart: always
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: imsdb
    volumes:
      # using volumes instead of bind mounts
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U "$$POSTGRES_USER" -d "$$POSTGRES_DB"
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 2s

volumes:
  postgres:
```

#### `Makefile`

I was running `make up_build` that runs `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up --build -d` and this is the part where is hangs on the build process for around 1 minute.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BINARY=authApp
APIGATEWAY_BINARY=apiGateway

up_build: build_authentication build_api_gateway
    docker-compose down
    @echo "Building and starting docker images..."
    docker-compose up --build -d
    @echo "Docker images built and started!"

build_authentication:
    @echo "Build authentication binary..."
    cd ../authentication-service && env GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o ${AUTHENTICATION_BINARY} ./cmd/api

build_api_gateway:
    @echo "Build api gateway binary..."
    cd ../api-gateway && env GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o ${APIGATEWAY_BINARY} .

down:
    docker-compose down
```

I tried uninstalling Docker Desktop in Applications (Mac M1) and reinstalling it but the problem still persists.

Could it be a process that's taking up the CPU when running Docker? Or the storage for volumes is full? I ran `docker system prune` too but it's still the same. Running a simple `docker-compose up` also takes a long time.

### Adding `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0`

```
docker-compose up --build -d
Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.308MB
Step 1/5 : FROM alpine:latest
 ---> 1dc785547989
Step 2/5 : RUN mkdir /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3b744c7dca2a
Step 3/5 : COPY apiGateway /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3d3bcba5ef89
Step 4/5 : CMD ["/app/apiGateway"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b6fcdff5430f
Step 5/5 : LABEL com.docker.compose.image.builder=classic
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8f67e117f601
Successfully built 8f67e117f601
Successfully tagged project-api-gateway:latest
Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.972MB
Step 1/5 : FROM alpine:latest
 ---> 1dc785547989
Step 2/5 : RUN mkdir /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3b744c7dca2a
Step 3/5 : COPY authApp /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bbed0acb97b4
Step 4/5 : CMD ["/app/authApp"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 75a7a12ab1ce
Step 5/5 : LABEL com.docker.compose.image.builder=classic
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6469ad6fb3a0
Successfully built 6469ad6fb3a0
Successfully tagged project-authentication-service:latest
[+] Running 4/4
 ✔ Network project_default                     Created                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s 
 ✔ Container project-api-gateway-1             Started                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s 
 ✔ Container project-postgres-1                Started                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s 
 ✔ Container project-authentication-service-1  Created
```

### Update

Commented out volumes `postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data` in docker-compose and it worked. Temporary fix though.

Comment: Try running it without buildkit disabled, that output might give you a better understanding of what is taking time. Use DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 when invoking docker compose, or just run docker build manually with that ENV flag. 

I've seen long delays when the working directory contain massive files/folder structures (e.g .git) that isn't excluded via .dockerignore file. Copying these unnecessary files to the docker build context can take some time. 1 minute seems excessive though...

Comment: @jishi Strangely enough, I ran `export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0` and `export COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=0` before running `docker-compose up --build -d` and it builds faster now... not sure why though... How do I fix this? I have added the output above

Comment: @jishi I found the problem, when I commented out `postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data`, it loaded so fast. There might be something wrong with the way Docker volumes work in my context with docker-compose...

Comment: @jishi unfortunately, the issue came back today... have tried your method as you posted but it still persists :(

Comment: You should still try to look at the startup logs for the postgres container. It probably tells you whats taking ot so long.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
```

For one of your services. Your postgres is slow to startup from the persisted volume you have declared:

```
volumes:
  postgres:
```

The state of that volume delays your postgres startup most likely (the change you made effectively deleted your postgres data from a container standpoint).

You should look at the startup logging for the `postgres` container, it should tell you what it's up to during startup. My best bet is that it is doing some sort of recovery due to forceful shutdown. Might be because of the `restart: always` which in my experience doesn't work the way you might expect, keeping the container lingering (and at some point, probably killed).

Make sure that postgres actually shuts down cleanly when you stop docker compose, make sure it has time to stop (I think default is like 10s before docker sends a SIGKILL signal). You can adjust that per container with the `stop_grace_period: 30s` setting in your compose file.

Answer (score 0):

*(Answer posted on behalf of the question author in order to move it to the answer space)*.

I realized that my Kubernetes Cluster was attempting to start on my Docker Desktop, causing an issue because my Minikube cluster was not running. This led to an extended timeout during the startup of my Kubernetes Cluster, consuming all the Docker Desktop resources.

Comment: Hi Jessica: if you wish to tick/accept this CW answer, that's fine. Or you can repost it under your account, and self-accept that one. If you prefer the latter, let me know, so I can delete this copy.